# How to use lightning output text

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

```javascript
<lightning-output-field field-name="Flagstatus__c" variant="label-hidden"> </lightning-output-field>   
<lightning-output-field field-name="Date_of_Visit__c"> </lightning-output-field>
<lightning-output-field field-name="Details__c"></lightning-output-field>
```

Here instead of using output field I have to return a text value from the wire method's data.

```javascript
 @track datadetails;
 @track datadate;
 @track dataflags;


 @wire(getSingleSitevisit,{recrdId: '$recordId'})
 WireContactRecords({error, data}){
     if(data){
         console.log('DataTestingSiteVisit@@==>'+data);
         console.log('Date'+data.Date_of_Visit__c);
         datadate=data.Date_of_Visit__c;
         datadetails=data.Details__c;
         dataflags=data.Flags__c;
         console.log('Details'+data.Details__c);
         console.log('pick>'+data.Flags__c);
     }else{
         this.error = error;
        
     }
 }
```

In this wire method I have stored the data of each fields into `datadate`, `datadetails`, and `dataflags`. Now, I have to get these fields in the html text fields. Is it possible using lightning output:rich text?